Why "no wandering domain" fails in parabolic basin?
Theorem (Sullivan). Every Fatou component $U$ of $f$ rational map is eventually periodic, that is, there exist $n > m > 0$ such that $f^n(U) = f^m(U)$
I am familiar with the proof: spread around Beltrami differential on $U$ first by pushforward along the forward orbit $f^n(U)$, then pullback to cover the grand orbit. Use measurable Riemann mapping theorem to conclude $f$ has infinite dimension rational map deformation, contradicting finite dimensionality of parameter space.
Consider $f(z)=z^2+z$ with parabolic basin $U_f$. We know there exist petal $\mathcal{P}\subset U_f$ so $f|_\mathcal{P}$ is conjugated to $z+1$ in right half plane. Then we can take $V \subset \mathcal{P}$ so that $f^n(V) \cap f^m(V) = \emptyset$ "wandering" (this is obvious in $z+1$ plane, so move it back to $U_f$ under the conjugation).
Question: Why proof of No Wandering Domain fails to rule out such $V \subset U_f$? I understand $V$ is not a Fatou component. What I do not see is how Sullivan's proof use property of Fatou Component.

The density of repelling periodic points has to do with this. They are not dense on the boundary of your V in contrast. This density permits the construction of some technical auxiliary results, see for example paragraph (5) of Sullivan's manuscript containing the original proof, or the discussion on page 413 of the same document. There is also a paper of Bers explaining the proof. Apologies for the vague comment, but I can't do better at the moment.

@Prelude I agree it has something to do with the boundary, but at the moment I do not see at what step Sullivan's proof refer to the boundary points.

The proof of Sullivan's theorem uses in very substantial way that the boundary of the domain is contained in the Julia set. The main part of the proof for simply connected domains goes like this.
Consider a continuous family $\psi_t:t\in R^n$ of quasiconformal homeomorphisms of the unit disk, where $n$ is large in comparison with
degree of your function, and such that
$\psi_s\circ\psi_t^{-1}$ act non-trivially on the boundary (are not restrictions of conformal automorphisms of the disk) for all $t\neq s$.
Assuming that you have a simply connected wandering domain $D$,
and using the Riemann map,
you transplant these hmeomorphisms to $D$ and obtain a continuous family of conformal structures on $D$, and spread them along the grand orbit, so that $f$ is conformal
with respect to these structures. Then by the Measurable Riemann mapping theorem, you obtain a family $f_t=\phi_t\circ f\circ\phi_t^{-1}$, where $f$
is your original function, and $\phi_t$ is a family
of homeomorphisms parametrized by $t\in R^n,$ where
$n$ is large enough (greater than the dimension of
the space of rational function of fixed degree $d$).
Then you obtain $f_t=f_s$ for many $t$ and $s$,
which gives a family of homeomorphisms commuting with $f$. It is at this stage where the Julia set is used: one studies the action of these homeomorphisms
on the Juia set. Since they commute with $f$, they
preserve the set of periodic points of any given order, and since this set is finite, and the family is continuous, they must fix each of these points. Since the periodic points are dense on the Julia set $\phi_t$ must be identity on the Julia set, so we have a family of homeomorphisms commuting with $f$, and these homeomorphisms are identity on the boundary of your wandering domain,
and this leads to contradiction with our assumption that our original homeomorphisms
act non-trivially on the boundary.
For full detail you may consult this paper:
M. Lyubich, Dynamics of analytical transformation: a topological picture.

Thanks for the answer, Prof. Eremenko.
The thing I'm confused is at which step we need the Beltrami coefficients are supported in  whole Fatou component? In my original post, if the Beltrami coefficients are only supported in grand orbits $f^n(V)$ (which are simply connected), it seems I still get quasiconformal $\phi_t$ that conjugate $f$ to itself in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, therefore $\phi_t$ is identity in $J(f)$. However such wandering $V$ exist.

@Ricky Simanjuntak: I amended my sketch, hope it is clearer now.

The short answer is that there are always plenty of homeomorphisms that commute with $f$ (any wandering domain gives some) but they are all =identity on the Julia set. So to obtain a contradiction one needs to construct many such homeomorphisms which are not identity on the Julia set.

This is very clear, Professor! I did not realize before that given $f$ rational map, there are infinite-dimension family of QC-self-conjugacy of $f$ given by Sullivan's construction. I thought since we get contradiction, such family does not exist.

Therefore we use the fact $U$ is Fatou component to say the original $\psi_t|_\mathcal{D}$ that we use to define the Beltrami coefficient, is conformally conjugate to the intergrating map $\phi_t|_U$. The existence of such $\psi_t$ that acts non-trivially in $S^1$ is what gives the contradiction. Thanks a lot for the help, your answer is very illuminating.
